# Recursively substitude all properties of the type to a predefined value in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given the type below:

```
type Person = {
  name: string
  age: number
  experiece: {
    length: number
    title: string
  }
}
```

Is it possible to construct the type below:

```
type FieldsOfPerson = {
  name: true
  age: true
  experience: {
    length: true
    title: true
  }
}
```

Update:

I came up with a solution below:

```
type TrueForKeys<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends string
    ? true
    : T[P] extends number
    ? true
    : T[P] extends boolean
    ? true
    : TrueForKeys<T[P]>
}
```

Is there a better way?

The rules for the substitution - everything not an object should be changed to `true`, recursively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapped type with `T[key] extends object` to differentiate whether to recurse or use `true`:

```typescript
type AllTrue<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends object ? AllTrue<T[key]> : true;
};
```

Then it's:

```typescript
type FieldsOfPerson = AllTrue<Person>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwLACgoipUBDAWwgC4pFh4BLVAcwOKlOepIFdyAjBG2IQAHpEYQAxtzyF2xADYQWwABY1UfQfGEKowBsGU06jFnqgBfAlYDcBAqEhQAgosUAVeDwgAeTwA+TBxLAG0AawgQKCYoKJBkADMoTwBdGk9I6LSoMWAVABNEKGR+ACtpYCgAfjcPb18A7JA04Jp6Xwd8e0d8Z2gAMQYIRWKAeSS4JDQQ9y8ff2mUVEDugmVq0Sph0YmphBWQuXYySg7FgBpLTm5OiGv5IjEJEZkaE-0oZVUNAyvLOxDMY7gCntZbHYgA)

Comment: Yeah, right :) looks nice

Comment: Array properties may need more checks... *Edit:* Oh, hey, looks like they work. :-D